# Returning unique User ID from Get-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm currently trying to prepare some automation using Exchange PowerShell commandlets.
I've faced some problem.

When running **Get-MailboxFolderPermission** cmdlet on Exchange server it's returning results, but **'User'** field in resultset looks like **DisplayName** of the user.
It's not unique and I need solution that returns unique user identifier (like **SamAccountName** or **UserPrincipalName**).

Following this post - https://serverfault.com/questions/503014/how-to-get-mailbox-folder-permissions-with-samaccountname-or-upn - I was able to use **User.ADRecipient.UserPrincipalName** property, but it looks that it is available only on Exchange 2013 instance, and can't be used on earlier Exchange versions.

I've also found some PowerShell function (http://pastebin.com/MQPLJ5pC) which is resolving **DisplayName** into unique user identifier.

It looks like it's possible to tie it all together, but I'm wondering if there is some simpler way achieving it.

I'm interested in solution that works on **Exchange 2007**, **2010** and **2013**.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User.ADRecipient.UserPrincipalName property works on Exchange 2010 also. The get-MailboxFolderPermission cmd does not exist for Exchange 2007 so you would need to look into [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641962%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for something universal.

Comment: Thank you for you input. This is what I've already found out and yes now I'm using EWS to gather data.